# I want to do a data validation (if one of the column A value matches one of the column value of C)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables `WC_EMPLOYEE`, `ABSENCE_EVENT`, `EMP_PROVIDER`.

I want fetch those ID where `HOURS_DUR` column of `EMP_PROVIDER` table matches `SUM(HOURS_DUR)` of table `ABSENCE_EVENT`.

```
select A.ID 
from A
join B on A.ID = B.ID
where A.HOURS_DUR <> B.HOURS_DURATION

  (select * from
  (select D.ID as ID, F.HOURS_DUR as HOURS_DUR
  from EMP_PROVIDER F
  join WC_EMPLOYEE D
  on D.ROW_WID=F.EMP_WID) A
  (select * from
  (select G.ABSENCE_YEAR as ABSENCE_YEAR, D.ID as ID, SUM(G.HOURS_DUR) as HOURS_DUR
  from ABSENCE_EVENT G
  join WC_EMPLOYEE D
  on G.EMPLOYEE_WID=D.ROW_WID
  where G.ABSENCE_YEAR_WID=(select MAX(G.ABSENCE_YEAR_WID) from ABSENCE_EVENT G)
  GROUP BY G.ABSENCE_YEAR_WID, D.ID) B))
```

I'm trying to fetch ABSENCE_EVENT table query in B table and EMP_PROVIDER table query in A table and then get the list but I'm getting below error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 0000- "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line 5 Column:2

Comment: I have three tables WC_EMPLOYEE, ABSENCE_EVENT, EMP_PROVIDER. I want fetch those ID where HOURS_DUR column of EMP_PROVIDER table does not match SUM(HOURS_DUR) of table ABSENCE_EVENT

Comment: "where A.HOURS_DUR <> B.HOURS_DURATION"  that whole section after does not make sense it is not part of a WHERE clause.

Comment: I'm trying to implement subquery, can you suggest the way